# Insert PieceInfo in merged document with ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, merge, itext

I have a process that merge several PDFs into a single PDF. This is working great.

At the time of the merge, I want to add a PieceInfo at page level to track the documents that were included into that merged file.

Let's say I have 3 documents in this order: Fester.pdf (2 pages), Gomez.pdf (2 pages) and Lurch.pdf (1 page). After the merge I will have 5 pages and each page would have a PieceInfo with the file name that was originated from. This way, if I go to page 4, I will know the page was generated from Gomez.pdf

During my search, I found this post: [Insert hidden digest in pdf using iText library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462211/insert-hidden-digest-in-pdf-using-itext-library/18465343#18465343) and I tried to implement the same in my process. The suggestion works great but I could not figure out how to store the information per page.

Here is my code:

```
public static byte[] MergeDocuments(DocumentCollection myCollection)
{
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;

    // Merged the document streams
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Create the iTextSharp document
        iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

        // Create the PDF writer that listened to the document
        PdfCopy pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream);
        if (pdfDoc != null && pdfCopy != null)
        {
            // Open the document and load content
            pdfDoc.Open();

            //Dictionary Entries
            PdfName appName = new PdfName("MyKey");
            PdfName dataName = new PdfName("Hash");

            //Class to add and retrieve the PieceInfo data
            DocumentPieceInfo dpi = new DocumentPieceInfo();

            //Loop through my collection. The document class has the BinaryFile and FileName
            foreach (Document doc in myCollection)
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(doc.FileBinary);
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    int nPage = reader.NumberOfPages;
                    for (int n = 0; n < nPage; n++)
                    {
                        //Trying to add the PieceInfo
                        dpi.addPieceInfo(pdfCopy, appName, dataName, new PdfString(string.Format("Info Doc: {0}", doc.FileName)));
                        importedPage = pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, n + 1);
                        pdfCopy.AddPage(importedPage);
                    }
                    // Close the reader
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }

            if (pdfCopy != null)
                pdfCopy.Close();

            if (pdfDoc != null)
                pdfDoc.Close();

            byte[] arrOutput = stream.ToArray();
            return arrOutput;

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And a small change to MKL solution, changing the input to a PDFCopy:

```
public void addPieceInfo(PdfCopy reader, PdfName app, PdfName name, PdfObject value)
    {
        //PdfDictionary catalog = reader.getCatalog();
        PdfDictionary pieceInfo = reader.ExtraCatalog.GetAsDict(PIECE_INFO);
        if (pieceInfo == null)
        {
            pieceInfo = new PdfDictionary();
            reader.ExtraCatalog.Put(PIECE_INFO, pieceInfo);
        }

        PdfDictionary appData = pieceInfo.GetAsDict(app);
        if (appData == null)
        {
            appData = new PdfDictionary();
            pieceInfo.Put(app, appData);
        }

        PdfDictionary privateData = appData.GetAsDict(PRIVATE);
        if (privateData == null)
        {
            privateData = new PdfDictionary();
            appData.Put(PRIVATE, privateData);
        }

        appData.Put(LAST_MODIFIED, new PdfDate());
        privateData.Put(name, value);
    }
```

The code above is adding the pieceinfo in the last page only :(

Does the page PdfImportedPage object have a way to get the catalog?

How can I include this information per page level during my merge process? After that, how can I get the pieceInfo from the pages? Just looping through the pages?

Comment: The `DocumentPieceInfo` class from my old answer only works with the *document-wide* **PieceInfo** structure. If you want to put per-page information in there, the name for that information needs to somehow include the page, e.g. `new PdfName("Hash" + pageNumber)`. As pages in the document may later be deleted or inserted, that is not optimal. You had better use *page-level* **PieceInfo** structures or (due to the imminent **PieceInfo** deprecation) *page-level* private keys registered to you, cf. @Brunos abswer.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that `/PieceInfo` will be deprecated in ISO-32000-2 (aka PDF 2.0). As an alternative, you can create your own key to add your own custom data. This is explained in my answer to the question [itext how to check if giant string is present on the pdf page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584783/1622493).

You are asking *Does the page PdfImportedPage object have a way to get the catalog?*

This is not the right question to ask. If you study [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584783/1622493) well, you'll discover that you need access to the page dictionary. You can add a `/PieceInfo` entry (or your custom entry) to this page dictionary and then later retrieve it.

Take a look at the [CustomPageDictKeyMerge](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/custom-keys-and-comments#1614-custompagedictkeymerge.java):

```
public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfName marker = new PdfName("ITXT_PageMarker");
    List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
    readers.add(new PdfReader(SRC1));
    readers.add(new PdfReader(SRC2));
    readers.add(new PdfReader(SRC3));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    document.open();
    int counter = 0;
    int n;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage;
    PdfDictionary pageDict;
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        counter++;
        n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
            pageDict = reader.getPageN(p);
            pageDict.put(marker, new PdfString(String.format("Page %s of document %s", p, counter)));
            importedPage = copy.getImportedPage(reader, p);
            copy.addPage(importedPage);
        }
    }
    // close the document
    document.close();
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

In this example, we add a special marker to the page dictionary before we import the page. As a result, this marker will be added to the merged document:

[image]

Take a look at the [CustomPageDictKeyCreate](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/custom-keys-and-comments#1256-custompagedictkeycreate.java) example to find out how to retrieve these custom markers:

```
public void check(String filename) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
    PdfDictionary pagedict;
    for (int i = 1; i < reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        pagedict = reader.getPageN(i);
        System.out.println(pagedict.get(new PdfName("ITXT_PageMarker")));
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

Please make sure that you use a *second class* name for your custom key. iText has registered the prefix `ITXT` with ISO for its custom second class keys. This prefix makes sure that different companies don't use the same key for different purposes. All keys starting with `ITXT` can easily be identified as keys created by iText Group. ISO keeps track of all these prefixes to avoid duplicates. Registration of a prefix with ISO is free of charge.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for your suggestion. I apologize but I haven't had time to check this yet. Hopefully, I will test this during the weekend. What it this tool that you use to see the PDF structure? :)

Comment: @UncleFester That tool is called [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/Products/itext-rups)