# Remove Annotation iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, itext, highlight

I was able to highlight text in a pdf but I was wondering how I could remove an annotation I just added. I add with the following code:

```
    PdfAnnotation highlight = PdfAnnotation.CreateMarkup(stamper.Writer, rectangle, null, PdfAnnotation.MARKUP_HIGHLIGHT, quadPoints.ToArray());
    highlight.Color = BaseColor.RED;
    stamper.AddAnnotation(highlight, page);
```

If I were to keep a reference of the `PdfAnnotation` itself like in a list, could I simply go back to it and use that to remove it?

A typical scenario would be if I had to highlight something and then perform a check later and realize it no longer has to be highlighted, can I go back and undo it. I was considering making a list of everything I have to highlight and then once I'm certain everything in that list needs to be highlighted, go ahead and do it but this way seems to be twice as slow as if I just went back and undid the highlight as soon as I found out. So If I at least kept a list of the `PdfAnnotation`, can I go back to the last one in the list and do something like `highlight.Remove();` if I already have the reference to it. Or would I have to tag the annotation and later loop the page for all the PdfDictionary and find that same tag.

Comment: Are you talking about 'adding and removing it one pass" or "adding it today and removing it tomorrow"? I'm confused because you talk about keeping a reference to an object which sounds like the former.

Comment: Hi Chris, I updated the question. please let me know if its still confusing .

Comment: Generally speaking, when calling `AddXXX` methods for most things (except `PdfDictionary` and other basic collections) it is assumed to be a one-way path that is written to the PDF and essentially done with. The only way to "undo" those operations would be to close the PDF and perform a second pass. There _might_ be a listener or event out there that you _might_ be able to implement to post-process before writing but honestly it would be much, much easier to just store your own collection of `Annotation` and pages, add/remove as need and then add to the `Stamper` at the end when you are done.

Comment: Alright I just wanted to know if it was possible to achieve . Thanks a lot Chris.

Answer (score 0):

`PdfAnnotation` extends `PdfDictionary` which means that you can add a custom entry to that dictionary. See my answer to the question: [Insert PieceInfo in merged document with ITextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617914/insert-pieceinfo-in-merged-document-with-itextsharp)

In this answer, I add an extra entry to a page dictionary: `ITXT_PageMarker`. Note that I used a *second class name* starting with the prefix that was registered with ISO by iText to avoid clashes with existing or future keys in the page dictionary.

By adding this extra key (in my case to the page dictionary; in your case to the annotation dictionary), you can search for this element (in my case the page; in your case the annotation) afterwards, in the finished PDF.

**Caveat:** this doesn't answer your question if you wanted to add the annotation and then remove it in one pass. As Chris Haas mentions in his comment, your question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Hi Bruno , I updated the question. please let me know if its still confusing .